# image covers my contents even after I put br and hr after the image

Tags: html, css

this seems very weird to me. I have a full sized image and at the bottom of the image I want to insert contents and the title. but thing is my image covers up the contents and the title. Using page source, I have realized the image covers up my contents. How do I let the contents out of the image, without affecting the size of the image? I tried hr and br but both won't work.

```
div class="row">
<div class='col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2'>
<img src="{{ news.get_image_url }}" class="className" > 
<br />
    <h1>{{news.content}}</h1>


</div>
</div>

.className {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It is because your img is `position:fixed` and it will display using top/left/right/bottom property. So, here it is display over the content.

Comment: if you use position fixed for image then why not use same for image's content like title , an other solution add a warpper div to image and its content then remove position fixed from image and add for whole warpper element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using fixed position which cause your image cover the text and it will be always in the same position even if you scrolled down

try get rid of this like

```
.className {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
display:block;
}
```

[see fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2p6qvjtd/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use position fixed.
You can fix this by giving the h1-tag a top-margin evenly large as the image.